# How to mount all video devices into docker container?

Tags: docker, camera, device-driver

Currently I'm using the devices flag through docker-compose like this:

```
devices:
      - "/dev/video0:/dev/video0"
      - "/dev/video1:/dev/video1"
```

But depending on the system I'm on there may be different amounts of devices. Like some computers will have webcams that might add another device to the list.

How can I just add all /dev/video* devices into the container?

Comment: When you run your container with `--privileged` option then all video devices should show up under your `/dev`, at least this is what I do when I want to expose all cameras within my containers.